# How to pass random parameters to SilkTest Workbench or Classic Record&Play Scenario

Tags: testing, automated-tests, workbench, gui-testing, silktest

I am new to `SilkTest` and I don't have any scripting background. What I need to do is to record some test cases and then play them to check my system. After getting used to it, I plan to learn scripting and dive into it, but first things first.

What I need is to pass random generated (or randomly read from a text file or pre-defined) parameters into the recordins so that every time I run the tests, different parameters are used. For example, there is a component in which I write some letters and the component filters the results based on the text. Then, I select one of the results. Now, instead of recording the same letters everytime, how can I use random given parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Active Data` in Silk Test.

It allows enhancing your visual tests with external data, for example from an Excel file.

> ActiveData testing enables you to leverage existing data in external files as input for powerful, comprehensive application testing solutions. ActiveData testing enables you to perform multiple transactions against test applications using a different set of data for each transaction without writing complicated code or compromising existing data.

You can find an introduction to Active Data [in the online documentation](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.borland.silktest.workbench.doc/SILKTEST-7E3A1C51-ACTIVEDATA-CON.html) or in the [tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0STyHX2tMI&list=PLF7358D07EB2F890A&index=8).

Answer (score 0):

I have a question, what version of Silk Test are you using, also, what client are you using (Silk Test Workbench, Silk4Net or Silk4J).  Each of these clients has the ability to receive parameters from an external source whether it is from a command line or from an external data file.

You indicate that you want **random** data, do you really mean random data or external data?  If it is random data that you want you probably need to use a random number/string generator for the client that you are working with (.Net code for Workbench and Silk4Net and Java code for Silk4J).

Comment: The version is the latest, I am using the trial version. I used only Workbench which is a record & play client. Yesterday, I managed to store an input into a local variable. That was something for me. What I require is (op) to use external **and** random data. Also, I want to use it with Workbench (not silk4Net or Silk4J). Is this possible?